# When should I be using asyncio over regular threads, and why? Does it provide performance increases?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a pretty basic understanding of multithreading in Python and an even basic-er understanding of `asyncio`.

I'm currently writing a small Curses-based program (eventually going to be using a full GUI, but that's another story) that handles the UI and user IO in the main thread, and then has two other daemon threads (each with their own queue/worker-method-that-gets-things-from-a-queue):

- a `watcher` thread that watches for time-based and conditional (e.g. posts to a message board, received messages, etc.) events to occur and then puts required tasks into...
- the other (`worker`) daemon thread's queue which then completes them.

All three threads are continuously running concurrently, which leads me to some questions:

- When the `worker` thread's queue (or, more generally, any thread's queue) is empty, should it be stopped until is has something to do again, or is it okay to leave continuously running? Do concurrent threads take up a lot of processing power when they aren't doing anything other than watching its queue?
- Should the two threads' queues be combined? Since the `watcher` thread is continuously running a single method, I guess the `worker` thread would be able to just pull tasks from the single queue that the `watcher` thread puts in.
- I don't think it'll matter since I'm not multiprocessing, but is this setup affected by Python's GIL (which I believe still exists in 3.4) in any way?
- Should the `watcher` thread be running continuously like that? From what I understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong, `asyncio` is supposed to be used for event-based multithreading, which seems relevant to what I'm trying to do.
- The main thread is basically always just waiting for the user to press a key to access a different part of the menu. This *seems* like a situation `asyncio` would be perfect for, but, again, I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement the queues? Do you use the `Queue` module and/or `threading`'s synchronization primitives, or do you periodically check if there is data to be processed?

Comment: @Phillip Yes, I'm using `threading` locks -- wasn't aware that `Queue` had synchronization primitives. Is that a better way to do it?

Comment: @velocirabbit The `Queue` module provides thread-safe queues. You should definitely be using that over anything you created yourself.

Comment: @dano Oh, I'm definitely using `Queue` -- does it have built in synchronization? Is there no need to use both `Queue` and locks then?

Comment: @velocirabbit It depends on exactly how you're using the `Queue`, but if you're just using it to pass a message from a producer to a consumer, you should be able to use it without any external locking. You just need to make sure you stick to `queue.get()` on the consumer side, rather than some kind of loop that checks to see if the `Queue` is empty before doing the `get`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> When the worker thread's queue (or, more generally, any thread's queue) is empty, should it be stopped until is has something to do again, or is it okay to leave continuously running? Do concurrent threads take up a lot of processing power when they aren't doing anything other than watching its queue?

You should just use a blocking call to `queue.get()`. That will leave the thread blocked on I/O, which means the GIL will be released, and no processing power (or at least a very minimal amount) will be used. Don't use non-blocking gets in a `while` loop, since that's going to require a lot more CPU wakeups.

> Should the two threads' queues be combined? Since the watcher thread is continuously running a single method, I guess the worker thread would be able to just pull tasks from the single queue that the watcher thread puts in.

If all the watcher is doing is pulling things off a queue and immediately putting it into another queue, where it gets consumed by a single worker, it sounds like its unnecessary overhead - you may as well just consume it directly in the worker. It's not exactly clear to me if that's the case, though - is the watcher *consuming* from a queue, or just putting items into one? If it *is* consuming from a queue, who is putting stuff into it?

> I don't think it'll matter since I'm not multiprocessing, but is this setup affected by Python's GIL (which I believe still exists in 3.4) in any way?

Yes, this is affected by the GIL. Only one of your threads can run Python bytecode at a time, so won't get true parallelism, except when threads are running I/O (which releases the GIL). If your worker thread is doing CPU-bound activities, you should seriously consider running it in a separate process via `multiprocessing`, if possible.

> Should the watcher thread be running continuously like that? From what I understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong, asyncio is supposed to be used for event-based multithreading, which seems relevant to what I'm trying to do.

It's hard to say, because I don't know exactly what "running continuously" means. What is it doing continuously? If it spends most of its time sleeping or blocking on a `queue`, it's fine - both of those things release the GIL. If it's constantly doing actual work, that will require the GIL, and therefore degrade the performance of the other threads in your app (assuming they're trying to do work at the same time). `asyncio` is designed for programs that are I/O-bound, and can therefore be run in a *single* thread, using asynchronous I/O. It sounds like your program may be a good fit for that depending on what your `worker` is doing.

> The main thread is basically always just waiting for the user to press a key to access a different part of the menu. **This seems like a situation asyncio would be perfect for**, but, again, I'm not sure.

Any program where you're mostly waiting for I/O is potentially a good for for `asyncio` - but only if you can find a library that makes curses (or whatever other GUI library you eventually choose) play nicely with it. Most GUI frameworks come with their own event loop, which will conflict with `asyncio`'s. You would need to use a library that can make the GUI's event loop play nicely with `asyncio`'s event loop. You'd also need to make sure that you can find `asyncio`-compatible versions of any other synchronous-I/O based library your application uses (e.g. a database driver).

That said, you're not likely to see any kind of performance improvement by switching from your thread-based program to something `asyncio`-based. It'll likely perform about the same. Since you're only dealing with 3 threads, the overhead of context switching between them isn't very significant, so switching from that a single-threaded, asynchronous I/O approach isn't going to make a very big difference. `asyncio` will help you avoid thread synchronization complexity (if that's an issue with your app - it's not clear that it is), and at least theoretically, would scale better if your app potentially needed *lots* of threads, but it doesn't seem like that's the case. I think for you, it's basically down to which style you prefer to code in (assuming you can find all the `asyncio`-compatible libraries you need).

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed response! It's already helpful, but I'll try to clear up some details about what I'm trying to do: the `watcher` thread is just running through an infinite while loop checking to see if certain events occur. When one of those events occur, it puts a specific method into the `worker`'s queue that the `worker` then carries out (the `watcher` has a queue that just has the function with the loop in it, but I just realized that's unnecessary as it doesn't consume anything else from either queue). Right now, the `worker` just continuously monitors for events.

Comment: So, thread summary: `main` thread handles curses UI and user I/O, `watcher` thread monitors various types of events (web posts, time-based, etc.), and `worker` carries out methods that `watcher` puts in its queue (can be things like make posts/responses, calculate things, etc.). If using `asyncio` wouldn't give me much of a performance increase, I might just use `threading` for now (since I'm on a deadline) and then rewrite it later with `asyncio` for practice.

Comment: upvoted, thank you for the super detailed response as well, my case is similar, i need to listen to a redis publisher in node.js to send data to python where i receive it, then need to create a numpy array to run some math on it like moving averages etc and then publish the results back to node.js with a separate publisher, has a few IO bound operations too like checking if the data sent by the publisher is continuous and if it detects gaps, poll an external API to get missing data, its a mixture of IO and CPU bound tasks, i am assuming asyncio only does IO well and would need processes ...